# Simplifying integral with Bessel Function

Tags: integration

How do I get from Step 1 to Step 2? Do I apply integration by parts?

[image]

Comment: What are $f$, $f_r$ and $f(r)$? What do you mean by $()_r$?

Comment: what is $f$? it seems to prove that $-\frac{rf_r}{f}\frac{dJ_3(\lambda_{3p}r)}{dr}=\left(r\tfrac{dJ_3(\lambda_{3p}r)}{dr}\right)_r$.

Comment: $f$ and $f(r)$ are the same and are arbitrary functions of $r$. $f_{r}$ is the derivative of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is integration by parts. The subscript of $r$ means $\frac{d}{dr}$ of the enclosed expression. It's best to stick to one notation or the other instead of mixing them. Then the integration by parts formula becomes clear. The first term is in the first integral is the only one being transformed, and it can be written as
$$
      -\int_{0}^{1}\frac{df}{dr}\left[r\frac{dJ_{3}(\lambda_{3p}r)}{dr}\right]dr
$$
Then the integration-by-parts becomes easy to spot.